# Xamarin UI Test referencing Xamarin.Android project throws errors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I am creating a `Xamarin.UITest` for my android project. I am following the [Microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/uitest-and-test-cloud?tabs=vswin). Everything works fine right up untill the last point:

> Add a project reference from the UITest project to the Xamarin.Android
>   project:
>
> [image]
>
> This will allow the NUnitTestAdapter to run the UITests for the
>   Android app from Visual Studio.

As soon as I add a reference to an Android project it gives these errors:

> NU1201: Project uitest.Android is not compatible with net461
>   (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1). Project uitest.Android supports:
>   monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)

Which makes perfect sense because obviously a `.Net Framework 4.6.1` library knows nothing about MonoAndroid.

I have also tried converting it to `.Net Standard 2.0` but I get a similar error:

> Error NU1201  Project uitest.Android is not compatible with
>   netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Project uitest.Android
>   supports: monoandroid81 (MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1)

**Strangely** the project still builds despite the errors. **BUT** these errors fail my automated build nuget restore with exactly the same error.

The reason the UI Test references the Android project is for the `Xamarin Test Cloud` to be able to call:

```
    if (platform == Platform.Android)
    {
        return ConfigureApp.Android.StartApp();
    }

    return ConfigureApp.iOS.StartApp();
```

You can't use `InstalledApp` or `ApkFile` methods in Xamarin test cloud

Have I misunderstood something or is this a visual studio / Xamarin bug?

*PS. I am using latest Visual Studio version `VS 15.8.0`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically won't reference your Android project in your UI-test project. The reason for this is that:

- You might test an app you only have the apk or ipa for
- Cloud solutions like Test Cloud won't have access to the source code and therefor won't compile the code.

I am using the apk like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DroidTest
{
    const string _droidPath = "../../APK/my-app.apk";
    IApp _app;

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile(_droidPath).StartApp();
    }
}
```

If you made changes in the Android project build and create a new apk. After that re-run your tests.

Comment: do you have a way to generate the apk after making changes? i.e. when developing and adding `AutomationId`'s and then rebuilding the apk